# How To Refresh a Bound DataGridView On CheckBox Click

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, datasource, rowfilter

### Goal

I need a way to set items as **Completed** by clicking on a `CheckBox` in my bound `DataGridView`. Once that is done, the item is no longer seen from the `DataGridView` due to a `DataView`'s row filter.

---

### Explanation

I have a `DataGridView` that is bound to a `DataView`.

```
Private Sub LoadLispImprovements()
    Private ViewLispImprovements As New DataView
    ViewLispImprovements.Table = Programs.Tables("dtLispImprovements")
    ViewLispImprovements.RowFilter = "Completed=0"
    Lisp_dgvImprovements.DataSource = ViewLispImprovements
End Sub
```

This `DataView`'s table was set to the following `DataTable`:

[image: DataTable showing Primary Key and Boolean Value (in red)]

This `DataTable` has its Primary Key set to the correct field. The `Completed` field has a red square just to show you guys that I set it as a boolean value.

Take a look at my `DataGridView`:

[image: DataGridView showing the result of the bound items]

Here is where I would click on the checkbox and the item should get filtered out (because the checkbox **ShowAll** is not checked)

---

### Problem

When I click on the `CheckBox` , the item stays in the `DataGridView`. In order for it to get filtered out, I must select another row.  Take a look:

[image: Improvement is checked, but remains in the Dgv]

And when I change rows, it finally goes away:

[image: Improvement has been filtered out but only when I tried selecting another row]

How do I get it to remove itself immediatly after I checked the completed checkbox?

*P.S: Yes I have the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event handler.*

```
Private Sub Lisp_dgvImprovements_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Lisp_dgvImprovements.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If Lisp_dgvImprovements.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        Lisp_dgvImprovements.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried with `Lisp_dgvImprovements.Refresh()` after `Lisp_dgvImprovements.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)`?

Comment: @equisde Yep. Didn't work either. I also tried it after saving to the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by ending the edit of the `DataRow` when the value of the cell is changed.

```
Private Sub Lisp_dgvImprovements_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Lisp_dgvImprovements.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If (Me.Lisp_dgvImprovements.IsCurrentCellDirty) Then
        Me.Lisp_dgvImprovements.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Lisp_dgvImprovements_CellValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Lisp_dgvImprovements.CellValueChanged
    '                    |-- The index of boolean DataGridViewColumn
    If ((e.ColumnIndex = 0) AndAlso (e.RowIndex > -1)) Then
        With Me.Lisp_dgvImprovements.Rows(e.RowIndex)
            If (Not .IsNewRow) Then
                With DirectCast(.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row
                    '     |-- The index of boolean DataColumn
                    .Item(0) = True
                    .EndEdit()
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```